# How does Angular handle the binding of $implicit in ngForOf

Tags: angular

While reading the documentation on structural directives, I stumbled across the section on how the `ngForOf` directive is translated into a `ng-template`.

As `*ngFor="let x of foo"` is transtlated into `<ng-template ngFor let-x [ngForOf]="foo">` I figured that it should be possible to write `<div *ngFor="of foo let x">` as the order of the bindings usually doesn't matter. However I got the runtime error `Can't bind to 'ngFor' since it isn't a known property of 'div'`

Not resulting in a compile error, supported my idea of this being valid syntax, but I couldn't figure out why this was broken at runtime.

Even after reading throught the [sources of ngForOf](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/directives/ng_for_of.ts) I couldn't figure out why the order of the attributes should be relevant in this context. I assume it has something to do with the handling of the `$implicit` variable.

Maybe someone with a better understanding of the internals of `ngForOf` could clarify this too me?

Answer (score 0):

Microsyntax in bindings is subject of compiling inside of Angular itself. As all compiler, it parses code to AST and then performs tasks, for example validation of "language" structure...

If you want to deep dive check [angular compiler github](https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/packages/compiler/src/expression_parser) where parser method *parseTemplateBindings* is good starting point...

EDIT: don't know what version of Angular do you have, and what kind of compiler do you use (Ivy, Runtime), but in general all version should behave as i described, and you expect...

Comment: This project specifically is still on Angular 8. Using an aot build, I get the same error at compile time